# How to create progress update control programatically in c# non visual web part in Sharepoint

Tags: c#, ajax, sharepoint, web-parts, progress

How can I create progress update control programmatically in a c# non visual web part in Sharepoint?

I am using c# and the goal is to creates a text of "Loading..." inside the ProgressUpdate control that becomes visible while the update panel is loading more content and then disappears when content is loaded. If anyone can help that would be awesome. I tried the following, but no luck. A button triggers the update panel and the update works well, but when I try to add an update progress it gets added into the page, but it never appears when I click my button that triggers the update.

```
UpdatePanel up = new UpdatePanel();
up.UpdateMode = UpdatePanelUpdateMode.Always;
up.ID = "Panel1";

UpdateProgress upp1 = new UpdateProgress();
upp1.AssociatedUpdatePanelID = up.ID.ToString();

upp1.ID = "UpdateProgress1";

upp1.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<p>Loading...</p>"));

Controls.Add(upp1);
```

Comment: Have you tried anything?  Post some code, perhaps?

Comment: Just added some code. Thought I added that when I posted. Anyway you can see above what I have tried.

Comment: SharePoint **is** ASP (or more appropriate, is built on top of ASP).  Anything you can do in ASP you can do in SharePoint.  A visual webpart is just a webpart that auto generates a user control which is added to the webpart.  This was added because in 2007 it was so common to manually create a user control and add it to the webpart so that you can use markup when coding.  I *highly* suggest you do so; there's no real reason not to.  If you can't use a visual webpart then just manually create a user control that you add.  Also, "it doesn't work" should never be in a question.  Explain that.

Comment: So is the update panel working properly and doing an async postback, and the only issue you are having is with the `UpdateProgress`, or are neither working?  I don't see where you add any controls to the UpdatePanel, or add it to the webpart (but if you say that that part is working properly it's enough; you don't need to show the code).

Comment: I found this http://forums.asp.net/t/1216644.aspx may be this hepls.

Comment: Yes the update panel is working well. This is the only new code I have added that is not showing correctly.

Comment: Thanks for the link mishau. Here is another one that has a c# approach. http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/office/SharePoint-2010-Developing-064c5fbf/view/Discussions#content

Answer (score 0):

Alright so here is what I have found. If you make an Update Progress control outside an Update Panel, then it will fail to be able to listen to the trigger on the update panel when it fires. More can be read about that at the link below.

http://www.mostlydevelopers.com/blog/post/2008/08/23/Show-UpdateProgress-when-using-an-UpdatePanel-with-Triggers.aspx

So since I'm doing it this way, I had to use a javascript work around. I had to use the getInstance() method of the PageRequestManager object to get the instance of the PageRequestManager class. I then added the functions for the asynchronous request when it is initialized and ends.  This will allow us to show our UpdateProgress control when an Asynchronous call begins and ends. (See Javascript Below)

```
//Function for postbackUpdateProgress
var prm = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();
var postBackElement;

function CancelAsyncPostBack() {
    if (prm.get_isInAsyncPostBack()) {
        prm.abortPostBack();
    }
}

prm.add_initializeRequest(InitializeRequest);
prm.add_endRequest(EndRequest);

function InitializeRequest(sender, args) {
    if (prm.get_isInAsyncPostBack()) {
        args.set_cancel(true);
    }
    //Get the element that asynchronous postback
    postBackElement = args.get_postBackElement();

    //check to see if any of the following controls activate sender request.
    //search is used to search for the ID name in the string that sharepoint spits out
    // as the ID.
    var controlA = postBackElement.id.search("DropDownListType");
    var controlB = postBackElement.id.search("UserProfileDropList");
    var controlC = postBackElement.id.search("MoreNewsLinkButton");
    var controlD = postBackElement.id.search("PreviousNewsLinkButton");

    if (controlA != -1 || controlB != -1 || controlC != -1 || controlD != -1) {
        $('*[id*=Panel1]:visible').hide();
        //show UpdateProgress
        $('*[id*=UpdateProgress1]').show();
    }
}
//After async postback complete, then show panel again and hide UpdateProgress
function EndRequest(sender, args) {
    $('*[id*=Panel1]').show();//use wild card in jquery to find Panel1 ID
    $('*[id*=UpdateProgress1]:visible').hide();
}
```

Please note that I had to do a search() for the ID name because sharepoint puts a bunch of text before your ID name and javascript would otherwise not be able to find it by the text literal of the ID alone. A wild card approach with jquery is used to find the panel by using:

$('*[id*=Panel1]').show();//use wild card in jquery to find Panel1 ID

to show it.

and

$('*[id*=Panel1]:visible').hide();

to hide the update panel when the async call is initialized. You don't have to hide the update panel, but my particular implementation looks more aesthetically pleasing if I do.